# Convert system clock (microsecond) stored in int64_t to float(s)?

Tags: c++, c

Currently I have a function, f(), which returns the current system clock in microseconds. I need to convert it to seconds, preserving several digits after the decimal point. I want to store the result in a float(is it long enough?).

But what f() returns is a int64_t variable; I tried many methods, like:

```
(double)(f() / 1000000) + (double)((f() % 1000000) / (double)1000000);
```

and:

```
f() / 100000.f
```

But what I got in fact looks like "1318395904.000000".

UPDATE:

What I want to do is to calculate FPS of my program. It seems converting it into second first is a bad idea. I rewrote my program like this, and both method work well:

(PS, av_gettime() is the function f() I mentioned.)

```
std::cout << "Yoooooo FPS: " << (float)5000000 / (float)(av_gettime() - prevFrameShowTime)
          << std::endl;
std::cout << "Current FPS: " << (double)5000000 / (double)(av_gettime() - prevFrameShowTime)
          << std::endl;
```

And here is the output:

```
Yoooooo FPS: 60.623
Current FPS: 60.6097
```

Comment: And what did the value from f() look like before the conversion?

Comment: Your first method is isn't good because you are calling f() twice.  You should call f() once, store the result in a variable, and use that variable in both places in your calculation.

Comment: Whazt is the motivation for doing this?

Comment: @vaughn-cato 1318398877210448.

Comment: @ed-heal For calculating FPS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your float has (assuming IEEE-754) 23 bits for the mantissa, how do you expect to store a 64-bit value in there without losing precision?

(The value you showed needs 31 bits just to store whole seconds, your precision is only to the nearest 128 seconds)

Comment: It's 23+1 (implicit) bits of mantissa if you want to be precise :-) It can store 2^24 - 1 precisely (and 2^24 using exponent)

Answer (score 2):

A typical 32-bit float will give you about seven significant digits of precision.  All your significant digits are being used by the whole part.  You'll need to use a double.

Answer (score 1):

First you convert it to `double`, then divide:

`double result = (double) f() / 1000000.0;`

Btw, yes, I would store the result in `double` here, not `float`.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to lose some precision, but this should work:

`(double) f() / 1000000`